# Unreal Engine C++ Spawn Actor Bug

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, game-development

I have a simple Puzzle Game.

It is a combination of multiple simple games. Since those games are rotated during the game, everything is spawned dynamically.
I have a problem with SpawnActor.

There is a class called XGame(AActor) spawned by level manager(APawn) . It is responsible for spawning actors for this specific X game.

XGame.cpp

```
const FVector ActorLocation = GetActorLocation();

const FVector StickLocation = FVector(0, 0, 0) + ActorLocation;
const FVector BallLocation = FVector(0, 100, 0) + ActorLocation;
const FVector CircleLocation = FVector(0, 200, 0) + ActorLocation;

UWorld* World = GetWorld();

AXStick* Stick = World->SpawnActor<AXStick>(StickLocation, FRotator(0, 0, 0));
AXBall* Ball = World->SpawnActor<AXBall>(BallLocation, FRotator(0, 0, 0));
AXCircle* Ball = World->SpawnActor<AXCircle>(CircleLocation, FRotator(0, 0, 0));
```

The problem is, everytime I spawn an actor its X coordinate is increased by 68. (I don't know why 68)

For instance;

stick is spawned at 0, 0, 0

ball is spawned at 68, 100, 0

circle is spawned at 136, 200, 0

all of them are ACharacter

I would be really appreciated if anyone can help

Comment: Please read [example]. You need to start a new program from scratch, and add the minimal amount of code that 1. compiles, and 2. reproduces the error when run. Then show us that code. That does not mean copy-paste your entire code base here. I/O can usually be replaced with static assignment for test programs like this. We don't need every part of your classes included. We only need the parts that cause this error to be reproduced. Right now my best guess is you have a static constant somewhere that's being incremented. 68 is hex 0x44  or binary 0100 0100 if that helps.

Comment: Maybe you have moved root component by 68 on the x axis? GetActorLocation returns root component's location. But that's just guessing. Check all components location in the relative to the root component at the moment you spawn actors. Also check the actor world location, this 68 cannot come out of nowhere. You can also close the editor, rebuild whole project and start it again, ue4 is sometimes buggy.

Comment: thank you both for your valuable comments, i have now solved it by changing them to actor, because when they are spawned, their capsule component is spawned at 0, 0, 0, so they are collided and moved on the x-axis. Another solution is to move their capsule collision.

@JohnFilleau i was thinking on creating a reproducible example, however i've never seen a single ue4 question with a minimal reproducible example. Because it takes too much time to create a project from scratch and test it.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. Please answer your own question and accept it so that others may be helped in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get it working correctly by changing base class of Stick, Ball and Circle to AActor. Because of the fact that Character classes automatically generates a capsule component. They were colliding and spawned characters are moved by 68 each time (default capsule movement radius of character is 34.0).